# Pandas iteration over rows for features calculation

Tags: python, pandas, performance, iteration

I have a pandas data frame and I want to calculate some features based on some `short_window`, `long_window` and `bins` values. More specifically, for each different row, I want to calculate some features. In order to do so, I move one row forward the `df_long = df.loc[row:long_window+row]` such as in the first iteration the pandas data frame for `row=0` would be `df_long = df.loc[0:50+0]` and some features would be calculated based on this data frame, for `row=1` would be `df_long = df.loc[1:50+1]` and some other features would be calculated and continues.

```py
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

bins = 12
short_window = 10
long_window = 50

# seed random number generator
seed(1)

price = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', freq='30min'),
    'value': randint(2, 20, 1489),
    'amount': randint(50, 200, 1489)
})


def vap(row, df, short_window, long_window, bins):

    df_long = df.loc[row:long_window+row]
    df_short = df_long.tail(short_window)

    binning = pd.cut(df_long['value'], bins, retbins=True)[1]
    group_months = pd.DataFrame(df_short['amount'].groupby(pd.cut(df_short['value'], binning)).sum())

    return group_months['amount'].tolist(),  df.loc[long_window + row + 1, 'DATE_TIME']


def feature_extraction(data, short_window, long_window, bins):

    # Vap feature extraction
    ls = [f"feature{row + 1}" for row in range(bins)]
    amount, date = zip(*Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(vap)(i, data, short_window, long_window, bins)
                                                for i in range(0, data.shape[0] - long_window - 1)))
    temp = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['DATE_TIME'])
    temp[ls] = pd.DataFrame(amount, index=temp.index)
    data = data.merge(temp, on='DATE_TIME', how='outer')

    return data


df = feature_extraction(price, short_window, long_window, bins)
```

I tried to run it in parallel in order to save time but due to the dimensions of my data, it takes a long of time to finish.

Is there any way to change this iterative process `(df_long = df.loc[row:long_window+row])` in order to reduce the computational cost? I was wondering if there is any way to use pandas.rolling but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: The minimum and maximum of df_long is always the same. If this is true for the task you want to solve then binning could be calculated outside of the loop.

Comment: The df_long dimensions will always be the same but they will change one row forward each time. Could you please tell me how this is possible to do it? Thanks

Comment: The maximum and minimum of a window never changes when it rolls forward and binning is always equal to the same array. I checked it.

Comment: How to have a pandas.rolling with a long_window length? I can't understand how this is doable. Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is the first try to speed up the calculation. I checked the first 100 rows and found out that the binning variable was always the same. So I managed to do an efficient algorithm with fixed bins. But when I checked the function on the whole data, I found out that there are about 100 lines out of 1489, that had a different binning variable so the solution below deviates in 100 lines from the original answer.

Benchmarking:
My fast function: 28 ms
My precise function: 388 ms 
Original function: 12200 ms
So a speed up of around 500 times for the fast function and 20 times for precise function

Fast function code:

```
def feature_extraction2(data, short_window, long_window, bins):
    ls = [f"feature{row + 1}" for row in range(bins)]
    binning = pd.cut([2,19], bins, retbins=True)[1]
    bin_group = np.digitize(data['value'], binning, right=True)
    l_sum = []
    for i in range(1, bins+1):
        sum1 = ((bin_group == i)*data['amount']).rolling(short_window).sum()
        l_sum.append(sum1)

    ar_sum = np.array(l_sum).T
    ar_shifted = np.empty_like(ar_sum)
    ar_shifted[:long_window+1,:] = np.nan
    ar_shifted[long_window+1:,:] = ar_sum[long_window:-1,:]    
    temp = pd.DataFrame(ar_shifted, columns = ls)
    data = pd.concat([data,temp], axis = 1, sort = False)
    return data
```

Precise function:

```
data = price.copy()
# Vap feature extraction
ls = [f"feature{row + 1}" for row in range(bins)]
data.shape[0] - long_window - 1)))
norm_volume = []
date = []
for i in range(0, data.shape[0] - long_window - 1):
    row = i
    df = data
    df_long = df.loc[row:long_window+row]
    df_short = df_long.tail(short_window)

    binning = pd.cut(df_long['value'], bins, retbins=True)[1]
    group_months = df_short['amount'].groupby(pd.cut(df_short['value'], binning)).sum().values

    x,y = group_months,  df.loc[long_window + row + 1, 'DATE_TIME']
    norm_volume.append(x)
    date.append(y)

temp = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['DATE_TIME'])
temp[ls] = pd.DataFrame(norm_volume, index=temp.index)
data = data.merge(temp, on='DATE_TIME', how='outer')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Yes indeed. So the problem with my code is that I want to create the bins based on the df_long data frame values. In this case, every time that df_long changes, the bins will change too and will not remain fixed. I checked your code and runs faster, but the results are not the same as my expected results, unfortunately.

Comment: I also have a precise function. It was not as fast, but still good. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I have tested the precise function too. Running in parallel takes 0.17 min and running the precise function takes 0.24 min to finish. The problem arises as I want to calculate the pd.cut for each different rolling window. Thank you for your time and effort